# Difference between Oracle Label Security and Oracle Virtual Private Database?

Tags: databases, oracle

I am working on a class project, and our lecturer ask a question with this title, I searched in net but I could not find a clear answer. if there is difference what are they?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle Virtual Private Database (VPD) is provided at no additional cost with the Enterprise Edition of Oracle Database. Oracle Label Security is an add-on security option for the Oracle Database Enterprise Edition.

Oracle VPD is a term used for several powerful security features like, fine grained access control (FGAC), application context and global application context. VPD policies are written using PL/SQL, and can be assigned to an individual table or view. An information request, that accesses a table or view protected by VPD, is modified according to the policy assigned to the table or view.

VPD policies can be as simple as enforcing access during business hours. VPD policies can restrict access by comparing the value of an attribute in an individual row with an application context value. Global application context allows an application context to be accessed across multiple database sessions, reducing or eliminating the need to create a separate application context for each user session.

Oracle Label Security is an out-of-the-box solution for row level security. No coding or software development is required, allowing the administrator to focus completely on the policy. Oracle Label Security provides an interface for creating policies, specifying enforcement options, defining data sensitivity labels, establishing user label authorizations, and protecting individual tables or schemes.

Data sensitivity labels provide a powerful and flexible method of restricting access to data. For example, data belonging to different organizations or companies can be separated using data sensitivity labels and selectively shared between companies by changing the data sensitivity label.

Depending on the complexity of the security policy, Oracle Virtual Private Database may be the preferred method for implementing your security policy. Oracle Label Security is best suited for situations where access control decisions need to be based on the sensitivity of the information.

Please search in internet little

Reference: [enter link description here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28529/faq.htm)https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28529/faq.htm